# SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063

Tags: python, pyspark

When the error in the title is given and you're asked to see SPARK-5063, what is SPARK-5063? Some sort error description? Where can I find it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what it'll be referring to, all Spark ticket/ issues are tracked on Jira and this is how the open source project is co-ordinated https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5063